# Loopback - $owner role with a "hasMany" relation

Tags: node.js, acl, loopbackjs

I've been reading the loopback docs about roles. They state the following:

> To qualify a $owner, the target model needs to have a belongsTo
>   relation to the User model (or a model extends from User) and property
>   matching the foreign key of the target model instance. The check for
>   $owner is only performed for a remote method that has ':id' on the
>   path, for example, GET /api/users/:id.

However, what happens when I have a "hasMany" relation and want to perform an action on some object like this:

```
PUT myusers/123/news/456
```

This would be my user.json:

```
{
  "name": "MyUser",
  "plural": "myusers",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {},
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "news": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "News",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on [this](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Create+new+models), [this](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Define+model+relations) and [this](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Define+access+controls). I've changed the `MyUser` entity to `Writer` entity, because I like it.

As the `Writer` entity has many `News`, the `News` relation and ACL should be something like this (`news.json`).

```
"relations": {
  "writer": {
    "type":"belongsTo",
    "model":"Writer",
    "foreignKey":"writer_id"
  }
},
"acls": [
  { // Nobody has access to nothing
    "accessType": "*",
    "principalType": "ROLE",
    "principalId": "$everyone",
    "permission": "DENY"
  },
  { // But everyone can read everything
    "accessType": "READ",
    "principalType": "ROLE",
    "principalId": "$everyone",
    "permission": "ALLOW"
  },
  { // And authenticated users can create news
    "accessType": "EXECUTE",
    "principalType": "ROLE",
    "principalId": "$authenticated",
    "permission": "ALLOW",
    "property": "create"
  },
  { // And the owner of a news can update it
    "accessType": "WRITE",
    "principalType": "ROLE",
    "principalId": "$owner",
    "permission": "ALLOW"
  }
],
```

And the `Writer` entity **has the same `ACL` rules** but this relations (`writer.json`)

```
"relations": {
  "news": {
    "type": "hasMany",
    "model": "News",
    "foreignKey": "writer_id"
  }
}
```

What really happens here is that, when you create a `Writer`, you must specify `email` and `password` becouse he inherited from `User` model. So if you want to perform the

```
PUT writers/123/news/456
```

You must be logged has a `Writer` which can be done in this endpoint: `/api/writers/login` (with `email+password`). This endpoint is going to give you the `Writer` token and then you'll be able to perform the update on the `News` if you has the `$owner` token on your header, url or form.

On the other hand, you can also get the user who is doing the `HTTP Request` and put that user has the news owner with a [`hook`](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Define+a+remote+hook).

Hope it helps. Regards.